# How to find the inverse z-transformation of this function?

Tags: z-transform

This is the function:

$\frac{23}{4z-1}$

So far I learned how to find the inverse z-transformation by referring to a given formula sheet that contains the inverse z-transformations for different functions; however, I cannot find an inverse z transformation for a function in this form, i.e., it does not have a **z** in the numerator.

I also cannot find the inverse z-transformation of this function:

$\frac{11}{(2z-1)^2}$

Edit: I understood how to find the I.Z.T. of $\frac{23}{4z-1}$, but I still cannot find the I.Z.T. of $\frac{11}{(2z-1)^2}$

Comment: $\frac{23}{4z-1} = \frac{23}{4}\frac{1}{(z-\frac{1}{4})}$

Comment: Do you have $\frac{1}{(z+a)^2}$ or  $\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$ in your table? If you do, and you really do understand your first problem, you can do it.

Comment: no, I do not have it.

Answer (score 0):

$ x(n) \iff X(z)$

Differentiating w.r.t $ z$

$ nx(n) \iff \frac {dX(z)}{dz}$

So,

$ \frac{11}{(2z-1)^2} = \frac{d}{dz} (\frac{-5.5}{2z-1})$